# any scripts to extract a cvs archive over time and move it into svn?

Tags: svn, cvs

We're migrating to svn, but once we do, our code history won't be available without looking separately at the old cvs codebase.  I was wondering if there is a fairly easy way to extract individual changes made in CVS one at a time, and apply them to svn, so we effectively migrate the entire project history onto the new version system

Comment: all I could find was cvs history -a -c which gets all checkins for everyone, but it yields only the operation, timestamp, uid, version, file and path.  I still don't know how to extract how much was changed.  I suppose I could do a specific cvs diff and parse the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cvs2svn project does this quite well, and also converts to git and others.

http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=2976